# SetAdapter for DeviceList at the Fragment. But does not work

Tags: android

(Not the same problem)

I want to do bluetooth device list at the fragment. My first activity sign activity and i added button for the bluetooth device list if user press
the button(without sign) than device list page should be open. But the according the my codes if i added `lvData.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);` in the mBroadcastreceiver3 function.
I have a lot of LOGCAT (below the my question).Whenever if I remove the this line i don't see any logcat but my device list hadn't seen on my app. (But i can see to device at log.d)
How can i solve this problem. Please help me thank you.
(Sorry for my English).

LOGCAT:

```
07-03 09:12:25.514 18406-18406/com.example.duygu.mybluetoothdevicelist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.duygu.mybluetoothdevicelist, PID: 18406
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.duygu.mybluetoothdevicelist.BluetoothListFragment$2@a7d633b
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.duygu.mybluetoothdevicelist.BluetoothListFragment$2.onReceive(BluetoothListFragment.java:98)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:925)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

***Probably my problem is in here:***

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3;

{
    mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ACTION FOUND.");
            //  mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mBTDevices.add(device);
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
                mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_list, mBTDevices);
               lvData.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);

            }
        }
    };
}
```

**MainActivitiy.java**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG =" " ;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    int test=0;
    FragmentManager fm;
    FragmentTransaction ft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       // mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        //bluetooth= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bluetooth);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        if(test==0) {
            StartFirstFragment();
        }

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public static final String TAG = " ";

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//Open bluetooth and show device list at the new fragment


                BluetoothListFragment devicelist = new BluetoothListFragment();
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, devicelist).commit();
 test=1;


            }




        });





    }


    private void StartFirstFragment() {
        SignFragment signfragment =new SignFragment();
        FragmentManager fm =getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout,signfragment).commit();

    }
}
```

**BluetoothFragment.java**

```
public class BluetoothListFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


    public static final String TAG =" " ;
    ArrayList<String> data;
    //BluetoothDevice mBTDevices;
    BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    ListView lvData;
    Button discover;
    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();


    public DeviceListAdapter mDeviceListAdapter;
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_list, container, false);
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,data);
        if (adapter==null){
            Log.d(TAG, "adapter null");


        }

        ListView lvData =(ListView)  v.findViewById(R.id.lvData);
        discover =(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.discover);
        lvData.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);
        lvData.setOnItemClickListener(BluetoothListFragment.this);
         mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(getActivity());
         enableDisableBT();
        btnEnableDisable_Discoverable();
        discover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                discover_devices();

            }
        });


        return v;

    }
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3;

    {
        mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                final String action = intent.getAction();
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ACTION FOUND.");
                //  mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

                if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    mBTDevices.add(device);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
                    mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_list, mBTDevices);
                   lvData.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);

                }
            }
        };
    }


    private void enableDisableBT() {
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: Does not have BT capabilities.");
        }
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: enabling BT.");
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBTIntent);

            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: disabling BT.");
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }

    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void btnEnableDisable_Discoverable() {
        Log.d(TAG, "btnEnableDisable_Discoverable: Making device discoverable for 300 seconds.");

        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2,intentFilter);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: called.");
        super.onDestroy();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1);
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2);
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)


    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {

                int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch (mode) {
                    //Device is in Discoverable Mode
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:

                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Enabled.");
                        break;
                    //Device not in discoverable mode
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:

                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Able to receive connections.");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Not able to receive connections.");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connecting....");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connected.");
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    };
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch(state){
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE OFF");

                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:

                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:

                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE ON");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:

                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING ON");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void discover_devices(){
        Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices.");

        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Canceling discovery.");

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            getActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void checkBTPermissions() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            int permissionCheck =getActivity().checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
            permissionCheck += getActivity().checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
            if (permissionCheck != 0) {

                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < LOLLIPOP.");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        //first cancel discovery because its very memory intensive.
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on a device.");
        String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(i).getName();
        String deviceAddress = mBTDevices.get(i).getAddress();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceName = " + deviceName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceAddress = " + deviceAddress);

        //create the bond.
        //NOTE: Requires API 17+? I think this is JellyBean
     /*   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to pair with " + deviceName);
            mBTDevices.get(i).createBond();

            mBTDevice = mBTDevices.get(i);
            mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(callbackinterface.this);
        }*/
    }







}
```

**DeviceListADapter.java**

```
public class DeviceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> {

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDevices;
    private int  mViewResourceId;

    public DeviceListAdapter(Context context, int tvResourceId, ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices){
        super(context, tvResourceId,devices);
        this.mDevices = devices;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mViewResourceId = tvResourceId;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

        BluetoothDevice device = mDevices.get(position);

        if (device != null) {
            TextView deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceName);
            TextView deviceAdress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceAddress);

            if (deviceName != null) {
                deviceName.setText(device.getName());
            }
            if (deviceAdress != null) {
                deviceAdress.setText(device.getAddress());
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: You get NPE on your adapter. Check if you get the reference from layout with findViewById

Comment: But its true.        ListView lvData =(ListView)  v.findViewById(R.id.lvData);

Comment: Please declare your listview global..

Comment: it already global